# Can I pack chrome a standalone installation package(exe/dmg) with some specific extensions in it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed a chrome extension to solve a specific problem. I'm going to distribute it. But I dont want to my user down a chrome then install a extension and change chrome setting in order to unforbid my extension.
I'd like to pack the whole thing into one installation execution. Users just need to download the installation program, install it, then they get a special chrome with my extension on it. Everything is done.
How can I do this?

Comment: You're probably not allowed to redistribute Chrome yourself. You could do it with Chromium, and presumably Chromium allows local extension installs..

Comment: Is it really that much trouble to click the install button on the webstore?